# How to strip symbol from pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to turn a column of text numbers into numeric values but there is a pesky " -" at the end of the values that I can't seem to get rid of.

Here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
items = soup.find("div", {"class": "items-grid-view"})

rows_processed=[]
for item in items.findAll("div", {"class": "item-cell"}):
    itemTitle = item.find("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    itemPromo = item.find("p", {"class": "item-promo"})
    itemPrice = item.find("li", {"class": "price-current"})
    row = []
    
    row.append(itemTitle.text)
    row.append(itemPromo.text)
    
    offer_tag = itemPrice.find("a") 
    if offer_tag:
        offer_tag.extract()
        
    row.append(itemPrice.text)

        
    rows_processed.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows_processed, columns=["Item Title ", "Status", "Price"])
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.lstrip('$')
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.rstrip(' -')
df = df.replace(',','', regex=True)
df.replace(to_replace ="-",
                 value ="")

isAvailable = "Available" in df["Status"].values
print(isAvailable)
display(df)
```

With the commands I've used I've been able to strip a     "C"     "$"    ","    and    "(2 Offers)" from the price value. But there's still a " -" after every number i.e.

```
500 -
450 - 
600 - 
1200 -
etc
```

How do I strip the space and dash from every value in the data frame column?

Comment: Strip all of that off in the first loop, BEFORE you convert it to a DataFrame.  Then pandas will be able to recognize that they are numbers.

Comment: What function should I use to strip it before converting it to a DataFrame? I'm trying to use (itemPrice.replace(" -", "")) but it's returning the error NoneType object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.extract or regex capture group to keep only the numbers -- and the decimal if there is one (otherwise you would have 45.00 become 4500).  If you have decimals, use astype(float), or if you have only integers, you can ignore the . and use astype(int).  Here are 2 ways to clean up your Price column, you only need one:

```
row1list = ['$500 -', 'www']
row2list = ['$4.00 -', 'xyz']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list],
                  columns=['Price', 'abc'])

# option 1:  regex capture groups
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace('([0-9]+)', r'\1', regex=True).astype(float)

# option 2:  extract
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.extract('([0-9.]+)').astype(float)

# print(df)
#    Price  abc
# 0  500.0  www
# 1    4.0  xyz
```

Comment: Terrific.  Option # 1 should work now, I originally forgot to put .astype(float) at the end, so it remained a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were on the right track with the string manipulation methods you were using. I tested it myself and `df['Price'].str.rstrip(' -')` had the effect of removing the trailing spaces and hyphen. All you're missing appears to be a call to `astype`.

```py
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(int)
```

Comment: df['Price'].str.rstrip(' -') is not taking away the space and hyphen in my output. It's strange because the df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.lstrip('$') works for the $ effectively.

Comment: I can't immediately think of a reason for that. Do you think the hyphen character that currently exists in the DataFrame is actually encoded as some other character?

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions to remove all characters that aren't 0 to 9.

Comment: when I try the astype code you gave me I get the error message "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '500\xa0–'" so I think you're right that it's encoded to some other characters. Now to figure out how to take the other characters away...

Comment: If the substring you want is a contiguous sequence of digits (characters 0 to 9), you could use `pd.Series.str.extract` to get the first substring that matches `\d+`.